# NCover vs OpenCover Accuracy

Tags: .net, ncover, opencover

I have been recently comparing .NET test coverage tools NCover and OpenCover. It seems that NCover reports higher code coverage percentage than OpenCover. Has anyone done any Proof of Concept to determine which tool has greater accuracy in code coverage?

Comment: I don't have NCover to look into this but if you look in the output of each tool you may be able to see why there is a difference. A tool like ReportGenerator or NDepend may give you a different answer as it uses a common output. Both NCover and OpenCover instrument the code but it is how it is instrumented that may account for the differences.